# PHP Year dropdown - show next 20 years

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that gives me a year dropdown showing a range of years (1950 to current year minus 18). I want to modify this to simply show the next 20 years from current date:

```
            <?php
//limit by age requirement
echo date_dropdown(18);
?>
<?php
function date_dropdown($year_limit = 0){
    $html_output = '    <div id="dob_select" >';
    $html_output .= '        <label>Renewal Date:</label>';

        /*days*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_dob_day"><option value="">Day</option>';
            for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
                $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $day . '">' . $day . '</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';

        /*months*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_renewal_date_month"><option value="">Month</option>';
        $months = array("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
            for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
                $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $month . '">' . $months[$month] . '</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';

        /*years*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_renewal_date_year"><option value="">Year</option>';
            for ($year = 1950; $year <= (date("Y") - $year_limit); $year++) {
                $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';

        $html_output .= '   </div>';
    return $html_output;
}
?>
```

The best I have got outputs the next 20 years, but not within the correct HTML select element - they appear before the other form elements. How can I make them appear in the correct place?:

```
    <?php
//limit by age requirement
echo date_dropdown();
?>
<?php
function date_dropdown(){
    $current_year = date("Y");
    $range = range($current_year, ($current_year + 20));
    $html_output = '    <div id="dob_select" >';
    $html_output .= '        <label>Renewal Date:</label>';

        /*days*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_dob_day"><option value="">Day</option>';
            for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
                $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $day . '">' . $day . '</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';

        /*months*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_renewal_date_month"><option value="">Month</option>';
        $months = array("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
            for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
                $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $month . '">' . $months[$month] . '</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';

        /*years*/
        $html_output .= '           <select class="form-control float-control" name="fp_renewal_date_year"><option value="">Year</option>';
            foreach($range as $r)
            {
               echo '<option value="'.$r.'">'.$r.'</option>';
            }
        $html_output .= '           </select>';
        $html_output .= '   </div>';
    return $html_output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please be aware of the 2038 problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

When working 20 years in the future, your application is probably going to fail in 2018

Comment: @AgeDeO While the concern is valid, getting the current year won't suffer this fate (this only affects 32-bit UNIX timestamps). Once that's done, incrementing it is not a big deal (2038 + 1 = 2039)

Comment: @Machavity - I understand that, but he probably going to save this to a database or some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not terribly hard. Modifying your loop, we add the condition for this year + 20

```
$this_year = date("Y"); // Run this only once
for ($year = $this_year; $year <= $this_year + 20; $year++) {
    $html_output .= '               <option value="' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you generate the years to display but, if you notice all the other output is being buffered in a variable called `$html_output` but you have directly `echo`'d your new year output so it will be send directly to the browser.

So change your new code to

```
foreach($range as $r) {
    $html_output .= '<option value="'.$r.'">'.$r.'</option>';
}
```

and all should be well

Answer (score 0):

Simple one line solution

```
for($i=date("Y");$i<date("Y")+20;$i++) echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
```